# Declarating multiple symbolic variables in Python

Tags: python, symbols, sympy

When I declare a single symbolic variable, it works:

```
>>> from sympy import var
>>> x = var('x')
>>> x + 2
x + 2
```

Now, for my purpose I need multiple variables, say, `s0, s1, ..., s9` and I also need operations like `s0 + 1`, `s2 - s1` etc.

What will be the code? This will not work for me (EDIT: I mean I can do that, yeah, but for that I need to change my existing code a lot):

```
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> s = symbols('s0:9'); s
(s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8)
>>> s[0] + 1
s0 + 1
```

EDIT2: `s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9 = symbols('s0:10')` is fine, but the number of variables is not fixed.

Comment: Why will this not work for you?  What are your requirements?

Comment: Basically, I have already written many lines, but overlooked this fact. Now, if I try to use this, then I have to split the code into two parts, take output from one part, modify it and then substitute to the second part!

Comment: How about `symbols('s0:%d' % n)`?

Comment: Or just `[ var('x%n' % i) for i in range(n) ]`?

Answer (score 3):

First off, you should use `symbols` instead of `var`. `var` does some magic to inject the Symbols into the namespace, and should only be used interactively.

If you want an arbitrary number of Symbols, you want the `numbered_symbols` function, which produces an iterator. [Here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#sympy.utilities.iterables.numbered_symbols) is the documentation. An example

```
>>> N = numbered_symbols('s')
>>> for s, _ in zip(N, range(10)):
...     print(s)
s0
s1
s2
s3
s4
s5
s6
s7
s8
s9
```

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine, not sure what problem you are having with this:

```
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> s = symbols('s0:10')
>>> s
(s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9)
>>> s[0] + 1
s0 + 1
```

If you want to set each to a variable, you can use multiple-assignment:

```
s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9 = symbols('s0:10')
```

This would be the equivalent of:

```
s0, s1 = Symbol('s0'), Symbol('s1') # and s2:s9 as well
```

Comment: This is rather a question what the OP wants than an answer, don't you think?

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND This line `s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9 = symbols('s0:10')` is OK, but I don't know the number of variables beforehand, so that I need something like `s'0:9' = symbols('s0:9')
`, which gives a `SyntaxError`